# NodeJS: Settimeout in prototypes

Tags: javascript, node.js

I recently started using NodeJS, but when I do

[image]

I'm getting errors such as:

[image]

What's the best way to do this?

My current solution is like this:

```
var that = this;
setTimeout(function()
{
 that.myMethod();
}, 3000);
```

Comment: Why did you post the code as images? Could you please replace with text? Use four spaces to have it formatted as a code block with syntax highlighting.

Comment: I agree with @bfavaretto, please post code as text. Images won't be picked up by the search engines, which makes it much harder for other people to find useful content on this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the old that=this trick, or use bind, since it's sure to work in node.js:

```
setTimeout(this.myOtherMethod.bind(this), 10);
```